# How to reset the page, go back to first page on wordpress ( wp_query,paginate_links)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I use the follow code to handle WordPress pagination. For instance, if the user goes to page 9, My code will echo this URL
'http://jjh.com/Cute/page/9/?post_per_page=60'.

My problem is this:
can I reset the page to 1 whenever I change the `post_per_page` number?
I allow the user to change this parameter, and I want to reset to the top when they use it.

```html
<?php
//I cut some unnecessary code
// I have a select dropdown to select post_per_page
$arg = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
   'cat' => $page_cat,
   'paged'   => $paged,
   'offset' => $offset,
   'prev_text'          => __('«'),
   'next_text'          => __('»'),
    'mid_size'           => 2
 );
  $wp_query = new WP_Query($arg); 
 echo paginate_links( $arg );

?>
```

Comment: What is the actual issue?

Comment: without any code related to changing  `$posts_per_page` how are we supposed to help?

Comment: I just try to make it simple. and $posts_per_page is not related to my problem. I want to know when the select change, then reset the page number

Comment: Cleaned up wording to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $post_type = 'post';
                $args=array(
                   'post_typr' => $post_type,
                    'cat' =>3,
                    'posts_per_page' => 6,
                    'paged'          => $paged,
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'asc'

                );
                $my_query = null;
                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

After adding this code use while query `<?php if ($my_query->have_posts() ) : 
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>`

After while query end tag use `<?php
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $my_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
?>`

And then close if statement. `<?php endif; wp_reset_query();?>`